# How can any user profile views have "0"?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, profile-page, users

Recently i have checked a user profile who have "0" profile view count. How it can be possible? Is there any bug or anything else that i don't know?

[image]

The user i found in Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Probably caching? The numbers are not updated every millisecond.

Comment: @deviantfan possible but, still it showing zero after 30 minutes.

Comment: Give it time, those stats may not get updated more than once a day or even weekly.

Comment: For those who want to investigate caching: [it now shows](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3773380/user3773380) 2 views.

Comment: Finally it has updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be [something](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) you can blame this on.

Comment: Now should we flag this as a link only answer? ;)

Comment: yeah, that was catching problem. thank :)